# notification opening a new window no matter what in Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, notifications, android-intent

I want to launch a notification. When I click on it, it opens a NEW window of the app.
Here's my code:

```
public class Noficitation extends Activity {

NotificationManager nm;
static final int uniqueID = 1394885;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent= new Intent (Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SchoolBlichActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    String body = " body";
    String title = "title!";
    Notification n =new Notification(R.drawable.table, body, System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(uniqueID,n);
    finish();
}
```

by the way, if i add nm.cancel(uniqueID) before the finish(), it creates the notification and immediately deletes it...

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to just add a notification in the notification bar, and when the user clicks it, it will launch the actual Activity. This way the user won't be interrupted in whatever he's doing.

Create the status bar notification like this:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon, "Hello", System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, myclass.class);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "My notification", "Hello world!", notificationIntent, PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0));

mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Yeah I think thats what hes trying to do.....It could just be a simple flag he sets to be triggered on the return of his post to the server or something

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to open a notification window in a current activity? Because if you are I dont think you need to launch it with an intent. You normally only use intents to launch new services or activities in your app unless youve built a custom view and activity/service which is to take place within the notification box. I see you have it set up in its own class which is fine but I think the way your doing it by default would open an entire new view.

If you need to launch a notification during a process or something like a button click you dont need to have the intent there.....or at least I never did :)  What exactly are you trying to achieve with the notification.

Comment: Well, im running a background service that checks every 24 hours for changes in a site. if there are changes, it launches the notification.
I tryed doing it in a regular class but I had problems with it...
If the app doesen't work in foreground, it is okay because it opens my main activity when I click the notification.
BUT, when the app is in foreground, it opens a new screen of the app, and then I need to close both of them...

Comment: Well without looking at the rest of your code that launches the notification it would be hard to give you my thoughts on it. Are you talking about a notification that posts in the actual notification bar on the device? Or is this something that the user has to have on.

Comment: lol I hate to point you to the android dev site but......             http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html    If I knew a little more about the whole thing I might be able to better help you :)

Comment: Are you sure your server side script is returning the correct variable? In any app Ive made so far in dealing with a client/server set up I usually double check my values being passed back to the client. Maybe your passing something back to the phone thats a long and is supposed to be an int or something silly like that........or you could post some of the other class code that calls your notification class and we might be able to figure it out for you :)